# Why is NuGet available in Powershell but not in cmd?

Tags: powershell, nuget

I'm running into a strange situation where running `nuget` from PowerShell executes NuGet, but when typing the same from the cmd it says:

`'nuget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Also, when running `(Get-Command nuget).Path` in PowerShell to get the path of the executable, I get nothing. I do get an NuGet entry in the list of aliases (with the `Get-Alias` command) like the following:

`Alias           nuget -> nuget.exe`

Strangely enough, the `nuget.exe` executable is nowhere in my computer.

Does anybody have any clue where PowerShell may be taking NuGet from?

Comment: Unable to reproduce on any environment available to me.  Sounds like someone set up the alias in a profile.

Comment: What do you see for `(Get-Alias nuget).ResolvedCommand|fl` or `(Get-Alias nuget).ReferencedCommand|fl` ?  It might reveal the nuget.exe file location, which may not be in cmd.exe's search %PATH%.

Comment: @leeharvey1 For some reason now the command is not found in PowerShell so behavior is the same in both terminals. I can't remember having done something to setup this myself (it's a corporate box so maybe something was there before). I will have your advice in mind and update here if I see this again. Thanks!